# Counter only update after ng-minlength check is completed

Tags: angularjs

ng-minlength when completes then counter updates ....it doesn't updates initially.
what should be the issue ..

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="_500">Title of the {{ ::CreatePostVm.postTypeTitle }}</label>
    <input name="postTitle" type="text" autofocus ng-model="CreatePostVm.post.title" placeholder="Write the title of your {{ ::CreatePostVm.postTypeTitle }} here..." ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="100" minlength="10" maxlength="100" required class="form-control" />
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-8">
           <div ng-messages="createPost.postTitle.$error" role="alert" class="ng-validation-messages m-t-xs">
               <div ng-message="required">Title is needed to summarize your {{ ::CreatePostVm.postTypeTitle }}</div>
               <div ng-message="minlength">Title should be minimum 10 characters long</div>
               <div ng-message="maxlength">Title should be maximum 100 characters long</div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-4">
           <div class="helper-text text-right">
               <span class="small text-muted">
                   <span>{{ CreatePostVm.post.title.length || 0 }}</span>/100
               </span>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

ng-minlength is a validation directive, if input is valid then only value is updated to ng-model,if value is invalid then it isn't updated to model.

For more info check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength).

There is an example of minLength, if minlength is not satisfied model value shows up as blank.

Comment: so..is there is any other way that the counter updates right after entering charatcter